# AWS: How to specify files changes to which would trigger CodePipleine build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a monorepo containing several sub-projects (microservices) stored on GitHub. I am trying to build it using the combination of AWS CodePipeline and CodeBuild. I would like to start pipelines depending on what sub-project has been changed. For example, if a file in a `service-1` folder is changed I want to run a service-1 pipeline, and I don't want to run build for `service-2` or `service-3`.

In Google Cloud Build, there is [a possibility](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger) to specify "included files" and "ignored files". I am trying to find exactly the same thing in AWS.

**Quastion:** How to specify files/folders changes to which would trigger a CodePipleine build?

Answer (score 2):

Like with many services in AWS, you'd have to build this yourself. There is a blogpost on how to customize triggers. It roughly consists of the following:

1. Create a CW event rule that triggers a lambda on codecommit repo updates.
2. Write the logic that suits your usecase in the abovementioned lambda
3. The lambda eventually emits a custom CW event
4. Configure your pipelines to trigger based on the custom event payload

Article can be found at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/